# Application running with POW won't start (bundler thinks gems are missing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

error is in this block

```
begin
  # Set up load paths for all bundled gems
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.expand_path("../../Gemfile", __FILE__)
  Bundler.setup
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound
  raise RuntimeError, "Bundler couldn't find some gems." +
    "Did you run `bundle install`?"
end
```

how do I know what gem it thinks is missing? I've done bundle install in my gemset and in the system ruby.

Is there a way to add the name of the gem bundler thinks is missing to the runtime error bundler message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried bundle exec before the ruby command you are trying to run?

Also, if you're using RVM I would advise creating a .rvmrc file in your project directory so the gemset is the one you need, they are of the form:

rvm use ree-1.8.7-2010.02@admin_app --create

This will reset your gemset and ruby version to whatever you specify when you come to that directory.

UPDATE: .rvmrc is deprecated, instead you create .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset. This means you can use rvm or one of the other ruby version managers.